# incompatible dimensions when using lapply(cor(x, 1:length(x))

Tags: r, correlation, na

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
a <- c(1,45,5,23,78,NA,NA)
b <- c(1,4,5,NA,NA,NA,NA)
c <- c(4,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
d <- c(4,6,7,3,4,23,4)

df <- data.frame(a,b,c,d)
```

Now I would like to get a vector with the correlation factors of each vector with its own length **omitting NAs**.

For example: `cor(df$a[!is.na(df$a)], 1:length(df$a[!is.na(df$a)]))` which returns me the linear correlation factor of (1,45,5,23,78) with (1,2,3,4,5)

When I apply the above written code on one single column, it works. 
However, when I include the function in the lapply function to get it for all the columns, I get an '**incompatible dimensions**' error. I understand that the incompatible dimensions error indicates that different vector sizes are correlated. However, how is this possible when I am correlating the vector with its length itself...?

```
result <- lapply(df, function(x){ o <-cor(x[!is.na(x)], 1:length(x[!is.na(x)]))})
```

I also tried, which also returned me the same error.

```
result <- lapply(df, function(x) {o <-cor(c(x[!is.na(x)]),c(1:length(x[!is.na(x)])))})
```

Comment: is it because `cor(4, 1)` is not defined?

Comment: I can't reproduce your error, the lapply statements seem to work fine.

Comment: Works well for me as well, but for the c column which gives NA (and it's normal because there is only one observation).  BTW, you don't need the "o <-" in your fonction in your lapply)

Comment: Are you sure your example matches your actual data.frame? Is it possible that your actual data.frame has some number of `NaN`'s or `NULL`S?

Answer (score 1):

have you try:

```
apply(df, 2, cor, y=1:nrow(df),use="complete.obs")
```

It's a more elegant way of coding your function.  It may work better for you as well.

Comment: Safer still `sapply(df, cor, y=1:nrow(df),use="complete.obs")`